# Memory DIMM slot install order

Tags: memory, ibm-xseries

Building my first server and have a small question that I'm unsure of!
We've purchased an X3650 M3 server, with 2 processors and 8 DIMMS of memory.

Now I am unsure of the memory installation for 2 processors. The server has 2 banks of memory slots, 1 set next to each processor. In the instructions, it has the order in which memory should be installed. The table looks a bit like this:

```
Microprocessor #     DIMM Slot Install Order
--------------------------------------------------------
        1            3, 6, 9, 2, 5, 8, 2, 4, 7
        2            12, 15, 18, 11, 14, 17, 10, 13, 16
```

Now, I have 8 DIMMS of memory. Is the table saying "if you have 1 microprocessor, use this the installation order of 3, 6, 9 etc, if you have 2 microprocessors, use the order of "12, 15, 18 etc"...

or is it saying that you separate the memory per processor (so perhaps 4 dimms of memory in each bank).

I hope thats not too confusing to understand!

Comment: The typo will be irrelevant to the answer. Its an IBM X3650. I'm not asking them because it is much easier to deal with a forum than contact the manufacturer, plus many people here would have built this very server and would know the answer

Comment: I've always found the right answer to these is: RTFM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently outfitted 2 3550M3s.

The system will use 4 DIMMs per CPU.  That means insert DIMMs in slots 3, 6, 9, 2, 12, 15, 18 and 11.

It makes a little more sense if you notice that physically the slots for CPU #2 are "backwards" from CPU #1.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't say "if you have 1 microprocessor, use this the installation order of 3, 6, 9 etc, if you have 2 microprocessors, use the order of "12, 15, 18 etc", it says that the memory dedicated to CPU 1 must be placed in slots 3, 6, 9, 2, 5, 8, 2, 4, 7 (in this order) and the memory dedicated to CPU 2 must be placed in slots 12, 15, 18, 11, 14, 17, 10, 13, 16 (in this order).
Obviously you won't give different amount of ram to the 2 processors, so if you, for example, have 2x 4GB dimms and 2x 8GB dimms, then you'll have to put 4GB in slots 3 and 12 and 8GB in slots 6 and 15, having same config for both CPUs.

Regards,
Alessandro